# C++ template function on a STL container

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers

I would like to write a generic function calculating sum of elements in a STL container. The way I go about it is as follows (`t` is a container):

```
template <typename T> double Sum(const T& t){
    typename T::reverse_iterator rit  = t.rbegin();
    double dSum = 0.;
    while( rit != t.rend() ){
        dSum += (*rit);
            ++rit;
    }
    return dSum;
}
```

but I'm getting a whole lot of errors. I guess the problem is about 2nd line where I define the iterator? Would appreciate any help :)

Comment: Like [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)?

Comment: What are the errors? Place at least the first ones

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be

```
typename T::const_reverse_iterator rit  = t.rbegin();
```

since `t` is `const` and `rbegin` for `const` container returns `const_reverse_iterator`, that cannot be converted to `reverse_iterator`.

Will be better to use `std::accumulate`, instead of your own function, like this

```
double result = std::accumulate(c.rbegin(), c.rend(), 0.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Would appreciate any help :)

If you are doing this in production code, use `std::accumulate` instead: it is standard, production quality code and should be already implemented and tested.

If you are writing this as an exercise, consider the following:

- define your function interface in terms of iterators, not of container. One of the greatest strengths of the std:: library is that is separates container logic (how do you get iterators and advance them) from the algorithm you apply on the iterators (in this case, `Sum`).

For example (with std::accumulate) you can call it as `std::accumulate(t.begin(), t.end(), 0)` or `std::accumulate(t.rbegin(), t.rend(), 0)` or `std::accumulate(t.cbegin(), t.cend(), 0)`.

- receive begin iterator by value and increment it directly (it will save you the need to declare rit internally; receive the end iterator by const reference.
- optional: set a default value for the sum (the default should be zero).

Comment: Iterators are nice. But boost for example use containers, or ranges in most cases.